# Can form-submission checkbox and blank field activity be seen on website's end?

Tags: php, html, form-submit

I'm talking about a php form such as the one seen here:

[image]

Say I typed my name and ticked one of the checkboxes, but DID NOT yet click submit.  Is there any chance the website operator can see what I've written (or even that I've simply entered text), or that I've ticked one of the boxes?

Of course once I click submit, I'm sending a request to the server and they can see what I've submitted.  But before I ever click submit, is there any chance they can somehow see my activity?

Answer (score 0):

If the page you are on uses some special technology (e.g. ajax) to send everything you type to the server, then yes. Otherwise, the default is a definite no. I've never heard of anybody logging this, but I guess it can never be guaranteed.

Answer (score 0):

No, not if you only use PHP in combination with HTML.

*However*, as soon as you **involve JavaScript**, there are definitely ways to send this information to the server. For example have a look into [Ajax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29).

Comment: Thanks, is there any way I can check if a page is using ajax?  Either by viewing the page source or otherwise?
@Joel Hinz

Comment: Well, you can definitely see it in the page source. If you don't see any JavaScript, you're good. If you do, you should have a closer look.